# What is the relationship between Podrick Payne and Ser Ilyn Payne?

Tags: game-of-thrones

They seem to share the same last name.

Are they related? If so, how?

Comment: Good question, have a look here: http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Payne

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Podrick Payne is a distant cousin of Ser Ilyn Payne, as detailed in A Game Of Thrones, Book One, Chapter 62:

> Podrick Payne, swallowed whatever he had been about to say. The lad was a distant cousin to Ser Ilyn Payne, the king's headsman ... and almost as quiet, although not for want of a tongue

Comment: Please add a reference for that quote.

Comment: @Mooz - I have done so, but I have a Kindle edition, so I hope the chapter number is right.

Comment: That's not a problem, as long as you mention that, people will get it :)

Answer (score 4):

They're distant cousins from different branches of the family.

Sources: [GOT wiki](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/House_Payne) and [IGN wiki](http://www.ign.com/wikis/game-of-thrones/House_Payne)